# Using a pre trained huggingface Summarization model on a pandas column based on a condition

Tags: python-3.x, huggingface-transformers, summarization, huggingface

I am trying to use a pre trained huggingface Summarization model "Facebook Bart CNN" [as mentioned here](https://huggingface.co/facebook/bart-large-cnn?text=More%20meaningful%20engagement)

I have downloaded the model into my local directlory and I am calling it from the same location on my pandas column to perform summarization of text based on a condition.
So my condition is if the text contains less than 30 words, it should return the text as is but if the text contains equal to or more than 30 words, it should be summarized based on the model that I am calling.

I have written the following code for the above:

```
#Calculate total number of words
df['totalwords'] = [len(x.split()) for x in df['feedback'].tolist()]
#Calling the model
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
from transformers import AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM
from scipy.special import softmax
path = r"C:\Users\xxx\bart-large-summarization"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(path,
                                     model_max_length = 512,
                                     truncation = True)
summarization_model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained(path) 
#Applying the model based on the condition above:
df['summary_feedback'] = np.where(df['totalwords']<=30,
                          df['feedback'],
                         df['feedback'].apply(lambda x: summarization_model(x)))
```

But as I am doing this, I am getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'new_zeros'
```

Any idea how this can be resolved?

Comment: Please show the full error stacktrace.